# cordova background geolocation not working on background

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

We have a location based cross platform app built using
Ionic. We had built the ability to receive notifications based on the
user location using the christocracy plugin at : https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.

Unfortunately, this works only when the app is open. Besides, there
is a display in the android drawer that background location is on.

We are unable to find an option where we can obtain user location
even after the app is closed and serve notifications based on the user's
location. Please suggest any solution or plug-in which can solve the purpose.

Comment: I've made a [plugin](https://github.com/blauharley/Cordova-Reminder) so far only for android that keeps track of the user's location/movements while they are in a app and after the app has been closed but at the moment I'afraid you have to modify my GNU-app in order that it shows notifications based by certain locations. But may be such feature will be added soon ;)

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no such plugin available that can fetch you location co-ordinates for the device while your app is in background / suspended / killed.

You must develop native android cordova plugin which can do so for you. Remember this will involve Native platform implementation.

Answer (score 1):

question might be old, but posting this might help others

using the following plugin you can fetch locations even if the application is in the background.
it has options like *'stopOnTerminate'* and *'startonboot'*, which helps you getting you location updates even after the reboot or OS kills the app

https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation